# How to manage Millions of rows displayed in a grid with limited memory

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, devexpress-wpf, ndatabase

I have a WPF data grid that is currently showing Millions of rows of type IMyObj. Now I already that part covered where we have to render whats needed. I am using [DevExpress's pLinqInstantFeedbackDataSource](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/clsDevExpressXpfCoreServerModePLinqInstantFeedbackDataSourcetopic) with [DevExpress's Grid](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Grid/). Which takes care of rendering only whats on display. But on the other hand, the actual data is stored in [ObservableCollection](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx&ei=qbxwUobJNuXnsAS484DwCA&usg=AFQjCNGjOPLQOpoBpclxg2htecuaZuSRaA&sig2=PFFw7upKCU8pNv4s2jwh6g&bvm=bv.55617003,d.b2I). Now DevExpress has said that my only issue is keeping stuff in-memory inside an [ObservableCollection](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx&ei=qbxwUobJNuXnsAS484DwCA&usg=AFQjCNGjOPLQOpoBpclxg2htecuaZuSRaA&sig2=PFFw7upKCU8pNv4s2jwh6g&bvm=bv.55617003,d.b2I).

I have evaluated the following solutions to store stuff in file-system and load only partial list of objects.

[NDatabase](http://ndatabase.codeplex.com/)

[STSDB](http://stsdb.com/)

Here is another issue, my application is using [dynamic objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264736.aspx). [NDatabase](http://ndatabase.codeplex.com/) does not support multi-threading to begin with and [STSDB](http://stsdb.com/) does not store dynamic objects well.

I would love for my application to be able to dump everything in file-system and when Gridview scrollbar location changes, it should trigger a load of only certain objects.

What would be your suggestion to manage that big data of [dynamic objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264736.aspx) ?

Comment: What's the point of showing millions of rows? Do you expect there are users who are going to read all those rows?

Comment: They will basically just take a glance look and hit save button to save a csv file. In future releases, they will be able to "Filter" records.

Comment: So your question is "how to keep/load in memory only what needed?". Well with pagination over a data source. Do you need ObservableCollection with DevExpress? Well, I suppose **no** (even if I don't know their components). How to do it? Show us what you tried. NDatabase doesn't support multithreading? Abstract access in a thread-safe layer.

Comment: @Adriano Pagination part has already been taken care of by DevExpress controls. I haven't tested to see if NDatabase works on dynamic. I lost interest when I found out they don't support multithreading.

Comment: @大师燈XiHuan: actually I can understand the requirement of the ops. When dealing with server log files, you have to be able to handle a huge amount of rows, with dynamic filters and formatting.

Comment: If they manage that then you just have to honor their request: "give me from #100 to #200". I don't even see why you have to load data in memory. That said you have to change from a dynamic object to something a DB can represent/store (unless you use, AFAIK, a nosql db). Catch the request, do the query, put db results to dynamic objects, done. Where do you put/keep objects in memory?

Comment: @Adriano I am sorry but my question is not should I or should I not do it. If you have any input, please share... The application connects to a server to download the log file which is displayed in grid. I have to save it *while* displaying it because download takes about 10 minutes and users need to see the stuff as it comes in.

Comment: Good to have the hint! IMO the point is you should _decouple_ them. You start downloading and go on with that. At the same time you ask for first page of data (well, datagrid will ask for it when you set a datasource) and a service will reply with required data (or less). User ask another page (scroll) then service will discard previous data and load new one (if available). Nothing to keep in memory. No matter multithreading (because everything will be serialized through the service, both reads and download). In theory to read data you don't have to care about size (and what is available).

Comment: BTW we're discussing about code and specific examples so it's hard to find a point. For something like that I wouldn't even use a "standard db" but I would check **MongoDB** (I suppose _dynamic_ nature of your objects fits well in a schema-less database).

Comment: I don't own the service I connect to. Service just streams the log file to me. There is no way I can call the service to request only one page.

Answer (score 1):

I can think about a copuple fo solutions:

- manually creating mapping configuration for your `dynamic` type and use any DB you want
- use a [Dapper](https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net), that according to the specification:

> Execute a query and map the results to a strongly typed List

But I never used it before.